# How to write following queries in $wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Migrate from `mysql` to `$wpdb` so I need to do following queries in `$wpdb` how to do it?

```
$result = mysql_query( 'SHOW TABLES LIKE "wp_%"' );
$table_descr_query = mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE sites");
```

I tried like

```
$wpdb->get_results( 'SHOW TABLES LIKE "wp_%"' );
```

but it doest not works and

```
$wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'")
```

it give only one `table name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this for to show all tables like `wp_`
the same thing you have tried but it will give you as a object , parse them like following , it works me fine.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( 'SHOW TABLES LIKE "wp_%"');
foreach($result as $index => $value) {
foreach($value as $tableName) {
echo $tableName . '<br />';
   }
}
```